# Carregar JSON via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Galera, estou tentando carregar um objeto json para exibir suas informações na tela. O código que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('tela', []);

  app.controller('TelaController', ['$http', function($http){
    var user = this; //testei com $http.get também
    $http.jsonp('info.json').success(function(data){
        user = data;
    }); 
  }]);

  var usuario = { 
    tipo: 'engenheiro', 
    maquina: 'XX160',   
    cliente: 'malhas',
    status: true
    };

})();
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="tela">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tela</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body ng-controller="TelaController as display">
    <header> <!-- cabeçalho -->
        <table align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3"><img src="imagens/logo.png" alt="Audaces a tecnologia da moda"></td>
                    <td><b>Acesso: </b> {{display.user.tipo}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="3"><b>Status:</b><img src="imagens/positivo.png" alt="status" height="15" width="15" ng-show="display.user.status"><img src="imagens/negativo.png" alt="status" height="15" width="15" ng-show="!display.user.status">{{display.user.ativo}}</td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Maquina:</b> {{display.user.maquina}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Cliente:</b> {{display.user.cliente}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>         
</header>
```

Quando eu fazia direto `this.user = usuario` funcionava, porém esses dados vou ter de ficar lendo constantemente. Sabem como resolver?

Comment: Por favor, explique melhor o contexto.

Onde está declarada a variável display, o que ela seria ?

`user` na parte onde você descreve seria o mesmo `user` que está dentro do controller ?

Comment: @FelippeTadeu `display` é um alias do controller: `ng-controller="TelaController as display"`

Comment: O que seria o constantemente ? Um setInterval por exemplo ?

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
app.controller('TelaController', ['$http', function($http){
  this.user = $http.jsonp('info.json'); 
}]);
```

(não estou em condições de testar agora, talvez esteja errado)

Comment: Não funcionou, mas valeu pela tentativa

Comment: não funcionou pois o retorno é uma promise e não uma coleção de dados  por exemplo.

Comment: `var source = this;
this.user;
$http.jsonp('info.json').then(function(data){
     source.user = data;
}); `

Comment: @FelippeTadeu Eu tinha a impressão de ter visto o angular cuidar disso "magicamente" alguma vez. Devo ter me enganado.